# Does CountDownTimer work if I close the app?

Tags: java, android

I use the `CountDownTimer` to send a message. I wonder does this work if I close the app?

Here is my code:

```
new CountDownTimer(waitTime*1000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
    public void onFinish() { forSend(); }
}.start();
```

Comment: maybe if you run it in a background [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: if run it in a background it still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you "close" an app is not necessary a "dead" app, when an app dissapear completely from the screen it goes to Stop state (calling onPause() and then onStop()) , then it take some time to call onFinish(), after that the app no longer exist as a reacheable app from directly onStart() to be called without making the onCreate() again, so as far as the timer still counting your app will be "alive" waiting for the counter to end and call the forSend() at onFinish() (the onFinish() from your annonymous CountDownTimer object) and the last thing the app do is the onFinish() from Activity Class of course, even if you overwrite it or not.

Comment: thanks a lot.what if i killed the app? it won't work,am i right?(sorry i'm a real real rookie)

Comment: if you call explicitly onFinish() (From Activity Class) it won't end the CountDownTimer, for better understanding you should do what @Hoan Nguyen said, set your CountDownTimer, explicitly call onFinish()  (again onFinish() from Activity Class not from CountDownTimer) somewhere before the CountDownTimer ends and check in your log if the CountDownTimer continue or not, im pretty sure it won't, by the way, this is not a rookie question, opposite, really good question.

Comment: really appreciated for your patience.

Comment: @rookie-hugo i have curiosity about this, did you solve this issue? and why not mark of correct answer? no that mine is necessary the correct answer but you should mark any you consider as a correct answer to help other to solve this problem if someone encounter it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `CountDownTimer` is still active even if the activity onDestroy() is called and `forSend()` would be called in `onFinish()`; Just put a log in onTick and you will see. However if you kill the app then the process would be killed and the CountDownTimer would also be killed.

Comment: thanks a lot.what if i killed the app? it won't work,am i right?(sorry i'm a real real rookie)

Comment: What do you mean by killing the app. If for example you kill the app by swiping the app in the recent app to the right, then the process is killed and the count down timer would stop.

Comment: thanks!that's what i want to describe...i killed the process and you are right!

Comment: I have the same issue. When I swipe the app to the right in recent apps, it closes the app. How can I fix this so that it still counts down?

Comment: You can't because by swiping the app process is killed.